# IMG2PY for background label and icon in TKINTER

Tags: python, tkinter

Working in a EXE file with background and Icon embed, I read some ideas about to use img2py in order to create module.py that can be imported into the EXE with pyinstaller.

I successfully create the imagebg.py (BG2.png Background) and imageico.py (ico2.ico Icon) modules using img2py. But there is no example or way to set that images into the modules in the tkinter label as background and the icon into the code.

Please anybody can help me.

Main code where must be imported BG ad ICON modules and use them as background and Icon images for tkinter GUI

#Main code GUI tkinter

```
import imagebg #from here we must import PNG_File.png for Background
import imageico #from here we must import ICO_File.ico for Icon
import wx #from img2py installation

from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

#set windows size
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("925x722")

#set title
root.title("SOFT1)")

#frame 1
f1=Frame(root, width=345,height=475,bg="light 
grey",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=4)
f1.place(x=20,y=235)

#set a image as BG
Logo=PhotoImage(file="PNG_File.png")
lab6=Label(root, image=Logo)
lab6.place(x=0, y=0)

#set a image as ICON
root.iconbitmap("ICO_File.ico")

mainloop()
```

The module imagebg.py for backgroud generated with IMG2PY

```
BG2 = PyEmbeddedImage(
    b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAsUAAAKECAIAAABgrdCGAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4b'
    b'AAAgAElEQVR4nOzdd2Ab5d0H8Oe0hy1vecYjcZw4cfYimwQIEEbYhQJlFgqU3UFZLR2M9i2l'
    b'tLRlFcouI5Qww15hZJEdO4kdOx7xtiVrj7v3DwdFlmXppu4kfT9/Wfbdc78YY339TMrpdBIA'
    b'AAAAAVRyFwAAAABJD3kCAAAAhEKeAAAAAKGQJwAAAEAo5AkAAAAQCnkCAAAAhEKeAAAAAKGQ'
    b'JwAAAEAo5AkAAAAQCnkCAAAAhEKeAAAAAKGQJwAAAEAo5AkAAAAQCnkCAAAAhEKeAAAAAKGQ'
    b'JwAAAEAo5AkAAAAQCnkCAAAAhEKeA..... to much characters to be placed in this post
```

The module imageico.py for icon generated with IMG2PY

```
from wx.lib.embeddedimage import PyEmbeddedImage

ico2 = PyEmbeddedImage(
    b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAsUAAAKECAYAAADvz0fRAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJ'
    b'REFUeJzs3WeAVNXdBvDnTi/b+7L0svSmIIKd2Gus0ZhiSeKreZOYmGpL15i8SdTEFKMpGkss'
    b'GEuMqNFYsCAgHRZYWFiWsn12p7f7fkBwy8zszC1z7537/L7ozs6c82dh4dkz/3OOEAgERBAR'
    b'ERERmZhF6wKIiIiIiLTGUExEREREpsdQTERERESmx1BMRERERKbHUExEREREpsdQTERERESm'
    b'x1BMRERERKbHUExEREREpsdQTERERESmx1BMRERERKbHUExEREREpsdQTERERESmx1BMRERE'
    b'RKbHUExEREREps.... to much characters to be placed in this post
```

Please any idea of how to use the modules as images for background and icon in the main code GUI Tkinter

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `wx.Image` to `PIL` compatible image if you want to use it in `tkinter` application.

Below is an example based on your posted code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import imagebg
import imageico

# function to convert a wx.Image to PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage
def wx2pil(wx_image):
    image = wx_image.Image
    w, h = image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()
    data = image.GetData()

    img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (w, h), bytes(data))
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('925x722')
root.title('SOFT1')
# use iconphoto() instead of iconbitmap()
root.iconphoto(False, wx2pil(imageico.ico2))

#set a image as BG
logo = wx2pil(imagebg.BG2)
tk.Label(root, image=logo).place(x=0, y=0)

#frame 1
f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=345, height=475, bg='lightgray', highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=4)
f1.place(x=20, y=235)

root.mainloop()
```

*Note that I use `wxPython` v4.1.0.*

*As it depends on wxPython, why don't you use `wxPython` for the GUI directly instead of `tkinter`?*

Comment: Thanks acw1668, your help is really amazing. I create the code to run on my PC but now I have more than 2000 lines of code that works perfect under Python and mi PC, all the problems arose when I decided to create an EXE so this situation taught me other new ways to do it better, one of them as well as you said is the use of wxPhython instead of Tkinter. Let me try your suggestions I will comment you the results.

Comment: Acw1668 thanks again, your solution was neat and flawless. Finally I create my exe as standalone. Thanks for your help.